# Does python expose an interface for parsing package metadata?

Tags: python, pypi, python-wheel

*Note: I am **NOT** looking for a way to interrogate installed packages in the virtual environment and do not want to load packages in order to parse them.*

I'm looking for a way to parse meta data from files [wheels and tar.gz] downloaded from pypi.  The format isn't so complex so I'm not really against writing my own. But given that python must be parsing this info inside `importlib` I wanted to see if theres a way that doesn't involve re-inventing the wheel.

I can see that `importlib.metadata` lets me get this information for installed pacakges. But I want to do this for a lot of versions of the same packages; many of which may not be compatible with the current virtual environment or even system architecture.

Does python (>=3.10) offer any interface for parsing wheel and tar.gz metadata without actually installing it into the virtual environment?

Answer (score 1):

This code searches for the METADATA file within the `.whl` file using the `zipfile` built-in library. The metadata is then parsed using `email.parser` to obtain a Message object, which can be accessed as a dictionary.

```
import zipfile
import email.parser

def get_metadata(path:str) -> str:
    # Open the file using zipfile
    with zipfile.ZipFile(path) as archive:
        # Find and read the METADATA file from the archive
        metadata_path = [file.filename for file in archive.filelist if "METADATA" in file.filename][0]
        metadata = archive.read(metadata_path).decode("utf-8")

    return email.parser.Parser().parsestr(metadata)


# Path to the wheel or tar.gz file
file_path = "numpy-1.25.2.whl"
METADATA = get_metadata(file_path)
print("Name: ", METADATA["name"])     
print("Version: ", METADATA["version"])   
print("Summary: ", METADATA["summary"])
```

Output:

```
Name:  numpy
Version:  1.25.2
Summary:  Fundamental package for array computing in Python
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download the files with `requests` and use [pkginfo](https://pypi.org/project/pkginfo/) to extract the data

```
from pkginfo import Wheel, SDist
import requests

urls = ['https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/06/6b1ad0ae8f97d7a0d6f6ad640db10780578999e647a9593512ceb6f06469/pip-23.3.2.tar.gz',
        'https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/aa/3f4c7bcee2057a76562a5b33ecbd199be08cdb4443a02e26bd2c3cf6fc39/pip-23.3.2-py3-none-any.whl']

with requests.Session() as session:
    for url in urls:
        response = session.get(url, stream=True)
        path = f'{url.split("/")[-1]}'
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.raw.read())
        info = SDist if path.endswith('.tar.gz') else Wheel
        data = info(path)
        print(data.name, data.license) # pip MIT
```